# RegEx to match last occurence of a string

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

For a Given paragraph,

> test of reg ex
>   This is a **test of foo bar. 
>
>   This is a** test foo.
>   This is a test of foo bar.
>   This is a test foo.
>   This is a *test of foo bar.
>
>   This is a* test foo.

Is there a way to match only the **Bold** or the *italicized* text above?

`/test of.*is a/s` would match from the first test and that is not what I want.

Can we perform this without using the Negative Look ahead?

I am working on some text manipulation using notepad++'s regex engine

Comment: And which is the "**Bold** or the *italicized* text above"

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see a preview button before I hit submit, I am fixing it already right after I posted it... you guys are fast..

Comment: `/.*\K\btest of.*is a\b/s`

Comment: Is it the whole document? Or part of a larger one? You say *or*: is selecting the italicized text sufficient: `test of foo bar\.\s*This is a(?![\s\S]*?test of foo bar\.\s*This is a)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[\s\S]*\Ktest of foo bar\.[\s\S]*?This is a
```

You can use `\K` here.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/47

Comment: Marking this as answer because the \K was really useful; Also I realized I asked the question poorly and didn't really solve my original problem, I re-asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050410/regex-match-closest-term

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use two regexes like these

```
/^[\S\s]*?(test of foo bar\.\s*This is a)/g
```

for **Bold** and for *Italic*

```
/[\S\s]*(test of foo bar\.\s*This is a)/g
```

Comment: realize i asked the question poorly and didn't really solve my original problem, I re-asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050410/regex-match-closest-term