# Regex match closest term

Tags: regex, notepad++

For the below paragraph, I am going to paste it into Notepad++ and use the Count functionality to find the count of "test of foo bar.\r\nThis is a"
I know I can do this using the "Extended" Search mode but my real life scenario requires regex.

> test of reg ex
>   This is a **test of foo bar 
>
>   This is a** test foo
>   This is a **test of foo bar 
>
>   This is a** test foo
>   This is a **test of foo bar
>
>   This is a** test foo

In plain English, I am trying to

1. Find location of "This is a"
2. Back track and stop at the first instance of the word test.

I am not too sure how to word the title, I'll modify it later

How about this? with random a1-f3 texts

> test of d1
>   test of e2
>   test of f3
>   This is a **test of a1
>
>   This is a** test foo.
>   This is a **test of b2
>
>   This is a** test foo.
>   This is a **test of c3
>
>   This is a** test foo.

Also would like to use the s modifier since notepad++'s . matches newline uses the s modifier. I almost have what I need in the below screen cap except for the first match, it matches too much.

[image: almost there]

sample text,
http://pastebin.com/xKJa8ECe

What I have now, which over matches
[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, since you're only using the count, what you have already should work, even though it overmatches.

Comment: Yes you are right! But after I get the count, I am going to be deleting the stack using the Replace functionality. As is, I am deleting more stack than I want

Answer (score 1):

```
test of foo bar[\s\S]*?This is a
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/48

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
test of .{2}\s+This is a
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Don't forget to **uncheck** the option `. matches newline`. (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>)

[image]

Tested on **Notepad 6.7.8.2**

Comment: Is there a way to solve the below paragraph, with the goal of finding count of *test* to *This is a*; the annoying thing is those a1-f3 are random. I over simplified my original example.... I am going through some call stacks so I dont want to post the real exact sample. 

test of d1
test of e2
test of f3
This is a test of a1
This is a test foo.
This is a test of b2
This is a test foo.
This is a test of c3
This is a test foo.

Comment: @freshWoWer Our answer will be more helpful to you if we can see the call stacks. What about 5 to 10 lines? However check my update. This time the regex doesn't rely on notepad++'s . matches newline.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan the a1-f3 are random length so the .{2} wont work, let me extract the simplified call stack and edit my question

Answer (score 1):

By your definition, shouldn't more text be selected, like this:

> test of d1
>   test of e2
>   **test of f3
>
>   This is a test of a1
>
>   This is a test foo.
>
>   This is a test of b2
>
>   This is a test foo.
>
>   This is a test of c3
>
>   This is a** test foo.

But anyways, since you're only counting, you can use this:

```
.test of.*?\nThis is a
```

to match what you wanted (including one character before the word test since it seems like you don't want any 'test' that begin a line

> test of d1
>   test of e2
>   test of f3
>   This is a **test of a1
>
>   This is a** test foo.
>   This is a **test of b2
>
>   This is a** test foo.
>   This is a **test of c3
>
>   This is a** test foo.

EDIT:
Not using '.':

```
 test of(\S|\s)*?This is a
```

Comment: is there a way to achieve this using the s modifier? Notepad++'s . matches newline option uses the s modifier and messes this up.  http://imgur.com/HgXge0x

Comment: Edited to not use '.'

Comment: There is a space at the front of test which makes it work for this specific example you provided, but overall, this method will not work for the actual snippet of text you provided unfortunately. I tried to find something that would work, but no luck so far.

Comment: My apologies for a confusing question with so much constraints... The Edit by you will over-match Unless I am mistaken, i.imgur.com/1GdEv1x.png?1 Actually, I am close, I tried again to play with \K and got the below, however it under matches.. i.imgur.com/03fCQiK.png?1  not quite what I need :( Appreciate your help! At last finally, I got out what I am trying to do... lol